# Service getting stopped when app closed in taskmanager

Tags: android, android-service

I am running a service in my app using below code in android manifest:
        `<service android:name="com.sam.cam.CallDetectService" />`

The problem is that the service gets closed when the application is closed from taskmanager manually, how can i keep running the service even if the application is closed.

I see applications like watsapp, gmail etc when closed using taskmanager still runs in background. How is this being done?

Comment: set the service `Service.START_STICKY`, so when the service is terminated it will restart. But not tested when terminated manually

Comment: I am already using Start_sticky as the return value..but still the service stops working after the app is closed from taskmanager

Answer (score 0):

You have to use " startForeground()" in your service class ,

example,

```
// on oncreate() of service class   
 Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("TOPAZ-PACS")
            .setContentText("")
            .setSmallIcon(com.emdsys.android.pacs.R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .build();
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    startForeground(1234, notification);
```

Comment: can put on onCreate() method of service or onstartCommand(). if you put oncreate()that will shows notification while service initialization. if you put on onstartcommnd() that will create and update whenever onstartcommand() call .

Comment: I have another question, why is notification required. What is a notification required to start the service in foreground